# Avoid initialized variables to persist across pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Apoligies if this is a noob question, but I am new and have a question about initializing and using instance variables in ruby on rails. I can create an instance variable like this in a model:

```
class MyClass
   def do_stuff
      @object_to_be_reused = []
      #make a DB call here populating the array with a bunch of objects
   end
end
```

And while I'm there on that page using that class, `@object_to_be_reused` works great as I only have to make a db call to set it once. However...

When I switch pages and come back later, `@object_to_be_reused` is still set to it's previous value. How do I re-initialize `@object_to_be_reused` such that, it is always not present when loading the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post more code, your controller too

Comment: I know you want to keep your intellectual property secret but you have to help out with what you actually want to do so we can help.

Comment: my controller is very simple, just making a call like `MyClass.doStuff` in the index method

Comment: How are you setting `@object_to_be_reused`?

Comment: apologies if i'm not being specific enough. I'll edit

Comment: is `MyClass` a controller? as far as I know, the controller is created each request, so instance variables should **not** be preserved across calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset a variable each time an action is performed (or for selected actions only) I recommend you creating a before_action / before_filter in the controllers and do it:

```
before_action :reset_my_class_variable, only: [:show, :edit] #applies to actions
before_filter :reset_my_class_variable #applies wide

#code

private

def reset_my_class_variable
   Myclass.do_stuff
end
```

Comment: The OP wants the opposite "How do I initialize @object_to_be_reused such that, it is always **not** present when loading the page?"

Comment: Yes, Uri Agassi is correct, I"m looking for the opposite of this. Still though, I appreciate the link, good reading!

Comment: You want to initialize the variable each time you load the page?

Comment: Is setting a before_filter a viable option? before_action :restart_variable; def restart_variable;MyClass.do_stuf;end;

Comment: Edited answer to the proposed solution in comments.

Comment: Instance variables should only persist for the duration of a single request, so they do need to be assigned each time in a `before_action` call.

Comment: Seems that he's not talking about instance variables but something like initializers. If you have a better answer feel confident to colaborate. Just comenting mine with: this is wrong doesn't feel like a nice practice.